# Does XBMC web service have a call to instruct the service to update its library?

Tags: xbmc

Does XBMC web service have a call to instruct the service to update its library?
I can't seem to find it in the documentation but this would seem like a pretty basic thing to include.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! In the current Dharma release, there is the HTTP API (deprecated) and the JSON-RPC API.
In a few weeks, with the next release (you can also download the nightly build, but beware of bugs) - the is a updated JSON-RPC API:
http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=JSON-RPC_API/v3#VideoLibrary.Scan

Sending this:

```
{"id":1,"method":"VideoLibrary.Scan","params":[],"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

Should do the trick for the next release. (TCP Port 8080 in my case)

```
{"id":1,"method":"VideoLibrary.ScanForContent","params":[],"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

For the current Dharma-Release.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small program that does that using Python https://github.com/asafge/TV_Mover